# Cannot implement Multiple Handler for a Consumer in RabbitMQ using EasynetQ Client for .Net

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, consumer, easynetq

I'm using Rabbitmq Queue solution and i have 4 queues and one consumer. i want my consumer consume all of these queues and provide separate Handler for each one.

I googled this and found that Rabbitmq and EasyNetQ (.Net Client for RabbitMQ), provides this feature with The Advanced API ([this link](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/The-Advanced-API) and [This link](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2013/11/easynetq-multiple-handlers-per-consumer.html))

The sample code provided in this articles to define multiple handler for a consumer :

```
bus.Advanced.Consume(queue, x => 
x.Add<MyMessage>((message, info) => { Console.WriteLine("Got MyMessage {0}", message.Body.Text); countdownEvent.Signal(); }) 
.Add<MyOtherMessage>((message, info) => { Console.WriteLine("Got MyOtherMessage {0}", message.Body.Text); countdownEvent.Signal(); }) 
);
```

**My Problem :
So when i try to use this example, the Add<> method is unknown. 
What is The problem? and what i should do to make this method available?**

my code's using part :

```
using RabbitMQ;
using EasyNetQ;
using EasyNetQ.Consumer;
```

My Code :

```
using (var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost;prefetchcount=100"))
            {
                var queue = bus.Advanced.QueueDeclare("QueueMessageTypes.VehicleDeviceChangeMessage:QueueMessageTypes_VehicleDeviceChangeMsg");

                bus.Advanced.Consume(queue, x => x
                        .Add<PositionMessage>((message, info) =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Got MyMessage {0}", message.Body.Text);
                        })
                        .Add<VehicleDeviceChangeMessage>((message, info) =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Got MyOtherMessage {0}", message.Body.Text);
                        })
                    );
            }
```

I think i should use a namespace or a class to use Add<> method. may it's a extension method that i should find and add related class from a library.

Answer (score 0):

After some search and test of many methods, i wrote the complete syntax of my code and ignored compiler error hint, and C# Compiler accepted Add<> method. 
after that it knows the Add<> method without adding any using part or other additional work.

but i have another problem that i think i should post it in separate question : 
I added handlers but they don't act any action on messages. the messages remain in queue.

my finall code that compiler accepts it (but doe not work):

```
using (var advancedBus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost;prefetchcount=100").Advanced)
            {
                var queue = advancedBus.QueueDeclare("MyQueue");

                advancedBus.Consume(queue, x => x
                        .Add<MessageType1>((message, info) =>
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("MessageType1 Body : " + message.Body.Body);
                                        );
                                    })
                        .Add<MessageType2>((message, info) => 
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(" MessageType2 Body: " + message.Body.Body);
                               }
                        )
                        .ThrowOnNoMatchingHandler = false
                      );
            }
```